# Volume of 3D shape with rectangle as base

Tags: volume, rectangles

The base is rectangular with $4 \times 9.5$ dimensions. There are three edges extending at a $90^\circ$  angle from the base with lengths $0.2, 0.5$ and $0.3$.

How would you calculate the total volume? Image attached for reference.

[image: Shape]

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is to use multivariate calculus.  Write a function for the plane that is the plane "above" the "base" and then integrate.

Comment: I believe that it's half the volume of a cuboid given your dimensions.(then again, I may be wrong) So find the volume of the cuboid and halve it.

Comment: Merely stating a problem, even one that can be resolved by mathematical reasoning, will not by itself make a good Question.  You should add context to the body of your Question, perhaps telling Readers what you tried, where you encountered the problem, or what makes it interesting or difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take your shape plus a mirror-reversed copy of it, they fit together along the oblique face to make a rectangular box with lengths $9.5\times 4 \times 0.5$. Since the original shape and its copy each have the same volume, that volume must be half the volume of the box.